# Android button spacing layout uneven

Tags: android, xml

I have an issue with my app where the button layout is not evenly spaced when used on different devices.

As shown, the first screenshot shows the layout evenally spaced out on an older, smaller screened android smartphone.

[image]

The second screenshot from a Nexus 4, shows the large white space under the bottom button that is uneven.

[image]

I thought I had set my layout to be even but it seems it isnt.

**UPDATE:
How to set a scroll view with the two linear layouts in it.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLink"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/appointmentmanimenuicon" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Appointments"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnaddAppoint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
        android:src="@drawable/appointmentmenu"
        android:text="Add Appointment"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnviewAppoint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointviewicon"
        android:src="@drawable/appointviewicon"
        android:text="View Appointments"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just curious what is the need of extra `ScrollView` there ?

Comment: android:layout_height="400dp" did you try making match_parent

Comment: If you remove the ScrollView and give both the outer LinearLayout a weight, what happens then ?

Comment: 1. Scrollview can only have 1 direct child. 2. Why do you need a scrollview for this? 3. Use a LinearLayout with weight.

Comment: @pasta12 Will that method work if I turn my device 90 degrees? I.e will I will be able to scroll to the lower button?

Comment: @user1352057 You won't need to scroll to the lower button. Using weight will adjust the spacing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested linear layout with the buttons has a fixed height of 400dp. On the small device this leaves a smaller amount of space at the bottom then it does on the larger nexus4.

If you change your linear layout with the buttons to use a height value of fill_parent it should place the buttons evenly in the space remaining in the parent layout underneath the header ( contacts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have sorted this layout issue but now have another issue where i cannot set my scroll view due to the two linear layouts. I have edited my question with the new XML.

Comment: Use `match_parent`, not `fill_parent`. `fill_parent` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your second LinearLayout has a fixed height of 400dp. The bottom edge of that layout will always be at 484dp (taking into account the first LinearLayout), and will leave extra space after it on any screen larger than 484dp tall.

I'm not entirely clear on what your desired layout is, but believe what you want is to center the second LinearLayout within the parent LinearLayout. 
To do so, add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
```

You should also consider removing the ScrollView, as that content should never need to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have sorted this layout issue but now have another issue where i cannot set my scroll view due to the two linear layouts. I have edited my question with the new XML

Comment: The error you should be getting is fairly straightforward- you can't have two child Views in a ScrollView. You didn't take any of our suggestions for fixing your original problem, and you have ignored the suggestion that nearly everyone has made to remove the ScrollView.